# Make a Python Script that can run two python scripts concurrently

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two python programs that I want to run. I want to make a python script which execute the two scripts concurrently. How can I do that?

Comment: You would need more than one processor. You could then run multiple processes concurrently (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html). You might actually want multithreading depending on what you're trying to do (https://medium.com/@nbosco/multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-in-python-c7dc88b50b5b).

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner: You **don't** need more than one processor, just an OS that supports multitasking.

Comment: @martineau but then is it truly concurrent?

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner: No, technically not—but depending on what the tasks are actually doing it may not matter. i.e. Such as when one is doing I/O and therefore spending a lot of its time waiting for physical devices. multitasking would prevent that from hanging the entire system down.

Comment: But is there a script to run two python scripts concurrently?

Comment: @Peppa what have you tried ?

Answer (score 2):

```
import os

import threading

def start():
    os.system('python filename.py')


t1 = threading.Thread(target=start)

t2 = threading.Thread(target=start)

t1.start()

t2.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` from the `concurrent.futures` library and be more flexible on how many workers should be spawned to execute your target script. Something like this should just fine:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Pool
import os

n_workers = 2

def target_task():
    os.system("python /path/to/target/script.py")

def main(n_workers):
    executor = Pool(n_workers)
    future = executor.submit(target_task)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(n_workers=n_workers)
```

This way you won't have to start your threads manually.