# How to make an application from two python programs?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, kivy

I have two python programs which one of them connects to a bluetooth device(socket package), it receives and saves data from device, and another one read the stored data and draw a real time plot. I should make one application from these two programs.

I tried to mix these two python programs, but since bluetooth should wait to receive data (through a while loop), the other parts of program does not work. I tried to solve this problem using Clock.schedule_interval, but the program will hang after a period of time. So I decided to run these two programs simultaneously. I read, we can run some python programs at a same time using [a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404043/make-a-python-script-that-can-run-two-python-scripts-concurrently). Is there any trick to join these two programs and build one application?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install threaded:

```
pip install threaded
```

Create a new python file:

```
from threading import Thread

def runFile1(): import file1
def runFile2(): import file2

Thread(target=runFile1).start()
runFile2()
```

Run the new python file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can run some python programs simultaneously on CMD (windows) or Terminal(Linux). I need to make an application which consists of these two programs. When an user open it, it will connect to bluetooth device and receive data and could plot real time data.

Comment: @tahami I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with threading.  To do communication between the threaded function and your main function, use objects such as queue.Queue and threading.Event.

the bluetooth functions can be placed into a function that is the target of the thread

```
import time
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue


class BlueToothFunctions(Thread):
    def __init__(self, my_queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.my_queue = my_queue
        # optional: causes this thread to end immediately if the main program is terminated
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self) -> None:
        while True:
            # do all the bluetooth stuff foreverer
            g = self.my_queue.get()
            if g == (None, None):
                break
            print(g)
            time.sleep(1.0)
        print("bluetooth closed")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _queue = Queue()  # just one way to communicate to a thread
    # pass an object reference so both main and thread have a way to communicate on this common queue
    my_bluetooth = BlueToothFunctions(_queue)
    my_bluetooth.start()  # creates the thread and executes run() method

    for i in range(5):
        # communicate to the threaded functions
        _queue.put(i)
    _queue.put((None, None))  # optional, a way to cause the thread to end
    my_bluetooth.join(timeout=5.0)  # optional, pause here until thread ends
    print('program complete')
```